# Open file matching a regex

Tags: regex, perl, file-io

I'm trying to open a file contained within the same directory as the program I'm running.

Rather than specifying the exact name of the file to read, I'd like to be able to match any filename ending in 'output.2.txt'. Something like this (but this doesn't work):

```
if ($input == 2) {
my $seqs =~ m/output.2.txt/;
open $genes, '<', $seqs or die "Can't open '$seqs'"; 
}
```

Comment: Did you try something like `m/.*output\.2\.txt/`? You have to escape the dots and without additional information your regex will only match exactly `output.2.txt`. And why do you use `'` ?

Comment: Try to use http://rubular.com/, it will help you to make your regex. Very simple to use.

Comment: That's a ruby regex site. Perl is: http://www.regex101.com/r/xV1vO6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to expand a list of filenames:

```
my @filenames = glob ("*output.2.txt");
```